# Catalog of all particles

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model

I recently watched a program on pentaquarks found in the LHC (potentially). They referenced a catalog of all particles.

What is this catalog of particles they are referencing?

Answer (score 9):

The [Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov) maintains a lot of high-energy physics data, including particle data. They’ve periodically published it in book and booklet form.

Comment: This is interesting... But it is not the reference I was looking for.  The one I was trying to find, may have been published by CERN.  Thanks though.  This will help.

Comment: In that case, they’re almost certainly talking about the PDG work and their Particle Data Tables and Review of Particle Physics.  http://library.cern/PDG_publications/review_particle_physics. There’s no other CERN-based comprehensive effort.

Comment: This looks like the document they were referencing.  Thank you